# How can I write the json array in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have this type of json

```
[{"width":308,"height":248,"fill":"#fff","radius":0,"blendMode":"normal","rotate":0,"strokeWidth":1,"stroke":"#b9b9b9","type":"rectangle","x":84,"y":46},{"width":260,"height":150,"fill":"white","blendMode":"normal","rotate":0,"strokeWidth":1,"stroke":"#b9b9b9","type":"circle","x":497,"y":104},{"width":69,"height":51,"fill":"#fff","radius":0,"blendMode":"normal","rotate":0,"strokeWidth":1,"stroke":"#b9b9b9","type":"rectangle","x":149,"y":112}]
```

I tried to write to the database in json format, but it gives

```
{"objects":[[{"width":308,"height":248,"fill":"#fff","radius":0,"blendMode":"normal","rotate":0,"strokeWidth":1,"stroke":"#b9b9b9","type":"rectangle","x":84,"y":46},{"width":260,"height":150,"fill":"white","blendMode":"normal","rotate":0,"strokeWidth":1,"stroke":"#b9b9b9","type":"circle","x":497,"y":104},{"width":69,"height":51,"fill":"#fff","radius":0,"blendMode":"normal","rotate":0,"strokeWidth":1,"stroke":"#b9b9b9","type":"rectangle","x":149,"y":112}]]}
```

controller

```
 def new
    @plan = Plan.new
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    @plans = @restaurant.plans
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json:  @plans.distinct.pluck(:objects) }
    end
  end

  def plan_params
    params.require(:plan).permit(:restaurant_id, objects: [ :width, :height, :fill, :radius, :blendMode, :rotate, :strokeWidth, :stroke, :type, :x, :y])
  end
```

I need a kind of json

```
{"objects":[{...}]}
```

**Update**

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :plans,  dependent: :destroy
end

class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

Comment: BTW which type of database field you're using for store your json object?

Comment: Also please put your data-scheme for Restaurant and Plan models.

Comment: @cnnr type json

Comment: @cnnr I'm adds the model but they have nothing

Comment: I kind of found something that I need to output `@plans.find(33).objects`

Comment: Few months earlier I've solved similar problem, but difference is that I prepare my json at client-side (from js-component) and saved it to text field. Shortly: I made my json object manually.

Your case is default RoR behavior, and I don't recommend use manual json prepare. Unfortunately, right now I've no time to completely test your case, but I'll try to do it few hours later if problem still wouldn't solve.

Comment: @cnnr JSON gives me reactjs, in general, I have solved the problem `render json:  @plans.find(@plans.pluck(:id).join.to_i).objects`. 
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to the following, to get json you want

```
@plans.distinct.pluck(:objects).flatten
```